# How to do math in SQL queries related to time stamps

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to do some math around a time stamp in a column in a MySQL database. I am using these queries within PHP to extrapolate values, then using them as variables to feed into another function that generates a Highcharts graph.

So for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(blah) FORM blah WHERE start_stamp >=now() - interval 1 day
```

but then I need to subtract from another value from a similar query to get the the count from the previous day, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(blah) FORM blah WHERE start_stamp >=now() - interval 2 day
```

So let's say these two become variables $today and $yesterday, how can I do this most effectively within a SQL query?  Obviously I can do the math within PHP but I am sure there is a better way to do this within the query itself.

Comment: Well while trying to figure out: Have you seen this is actually documented as well and you can read about it? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: 1 hour = 3600 seconds, 1 day = 86400 seconds, 1 week = 604800 seconds. Memorize these and after that use date libraries because months and years have variable lengths.

Comment: @Sammitch: `1 hour = 3600 seconds, 1 day = 86400 seconds, 1 week = 604800 seconds` --- neither of these is absolutely true

Comment: @zerkms true. date libs all of the every time.

Comment: If the variables are formatted in MySQL datetime format ('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') then your query can remain the same. SELECT COUNT(blah) FROM blah WHERE start_stampe >= '2013-08-23 12:45:00' - interval 2 day;. Otherwise if it's in unix timestamp format just use the FROM_UNIXTIME() MySQL function.

Comment: @sn00k4h it looks like an answer, smells like an answer but was posted as a comment...

Comment: Got this all figured out, thanks for the documentation link.